# Sonarqube Update Rule through Web-API

Tags: sonarqube

I am currently trying to update update a rule through the web api of sonarqube.  I was trying to pass information like Serverity, Description and Remediation Function with the post request with the parameters according to the web api documentation. Everytime I tried to do that I got a response of 400.

But when I edited the request parameters to pass only the markdown_note and the key it worked and the note was set.

I honestly don't know what I am missing. According to the documentation it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the api/rules web services is :

> Get and update some details of automatic rules, and manage custom
>   rules.

You can only update custom rules, not rules provided by language plugins.

The only exception to this is indeed the fact that you can add some notes on all rules.

Comment: I tried updating a custom rule (a rule I created through a custom plugin) with the same result. If this is what you meant with custom rule.

Comment: In fact I was talking about rule created from template user in the UI (or by using WS)